# Modifying Safari for Fluid

Tags: macos, safari, osx-leopard, fluid

Fluid is a really good app, but I can't see myself going over to a stack (like my Documents folder on the Dock) and opening it when I can just create a new tab in Safari. Is there any way I can modify Safari to force it to open the Fluid app when I enter a url that I created a Fluid app for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choosy is an app for doing exactly this [-website here-](http://www.choosyosx.com/).  It lets you setup advanced behavior rules that can essentially say: "see this url configuration -> open it up in this browser" (see screenshot below).  At first glance it looks like the rules pane is very configurable.

There is even a utility for it called (choosy fluid) [Get it Here](http://www.choosyosx.com/browsers) that will detect fluid instances on your mac and setup the appropriate advanced browser rules in Choosy so that the right links point you to the right fluid apps.

Don't forget to grab the browser plugin so that the rules you setup can be triggered from Safari.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use Cruz: [Essentially fluid as a browser](http://cruzapp.com/)

Comment: What I'm trying to do, though, is make sure that each website is run as a different process, such as Chrome's crash control. But Chrome isn't finalized for Mac yet, so I'm using Fluid instead.

Comment: So just to be clear: While in Safari, if you browse across a link to someone's user page on twitter (and if you have a fluid app setup for twitter) you would want the link to automatically open up in that twitter fluid app instead of safari when you click on it. Yes?

Comment: Yes.